# There are no instances of the User Profile Service started on any server in this farm. Which timer job throw this error?

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, timer-jobs

Why below error messages in a SharePoint application even i did not enable and no need  user profile and user profile synchronization service

> There are no instances of the User Profile Service started on any
>   server in this farm. Ensure that at least one instance is started on
>   an application server in the farm using the Services on Server page in
>   Central Administration.

Which timer jobs throws this error?

Comment: did you check the central admin > monitoring > health rule?

Comment: Actually, that seems to be some functionality attempting to use the user profile service that you did not enable, not the service failing. Try to pinpoint what feature is trying to use the service in the first place. Is your site collection/web application doing something that involve user profiles?

Comment: hi how to check which features is trying to use user profile in our web application?